# Error : Parameterized query 'INSERT INTO Altitude (DataID, Height) VALUES (@ID, @Height) ' expects a parameter value which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server CE database and C# language. I have a table with a **bigint** typed column. When I use a foreach loop for inserting some data :

```
 foreach (int alt in lsAltitudes)
 {
     Query =   "INSERT INTO Altitude (DataID, Height) " +
                "VALUES (@ID, @Height) ";

     using (var SQLCmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query))
     {
         SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", DataID);
         SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Height", alt);
         con.CeExecuteNonQuery(SQLCmd);
     }
 }
```

**Getting an error :** 
*Parameterized query 'INSERT INTO Altitude (DataID, Height) VALUES (@ID, @Height) ' expects a parameter value which was not supplied.*

My DataID variable's type is **long** by the way. I think it's somehow about converting bigint and a long value. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Are you **sure** `DataID` is not `null` ? (obviously `alt` can't be, since it is clearly `int`)

Comment: Actually DataID is a foreign key. Guess the problem was about that. Not null but some value which doesn't exist in the key table. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: no, that would be a different error. A SqlException with a foreign key violation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken it should be so

```
using (var SQLCmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query)) 
{ 
     SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = DataID; 
     SQLCmd.Parameters.Add("@Height", SqlDbType.Int).Value = alt; 
     con.CeExecuteNonQuery(SQLCmd); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overload of the Add method and specify the datatype explicitly

```
command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = DataID
```

Comment: or inline: `command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = DataID;`